# How to sum up array of objects by property or number array

Tags: typescript

I have a simple existing method that sums up object array by one of the properties.

```
const calculateSum = <T extends object, K extends keyof T>(array: T[], property : K) : number =>{
  
  let total = 0;
  if (property)
  {
      total = array.reduce((acc, item) => {
      return acc + (+item[property]);
    }, 0);

  }
  return total;
}
```

How can this method be refactored so array `number[]` can be passed as well and just to total it up in this case. How to not require `property` passed in this case?

Comment: Wait, why would you want to have one function to perform two distinct operations?  The implementation will look like two separate functions with an `if` statement to choose between them, and the call signature will likely be an overloaded pair of two separate call signatures.  It's like duct taping a hammer to a screwdriver and calling it a single tool. I mean, it's not *impossible* or anything, but what purpose is served that isn't better served by having them separate?

Comment: pls read prev comment.  Like, [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wEj4VN) is one way to do it, but yuck.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Would want to do it this way only if it's an easy enough implementation. Agree operations are distinct, but they have common denominator - sum up array of numbers.

Comment: Checked it out, thanks! It's less then elegant, no doubt but still good enough for me :-)

Comment: So shall I write up an answer with the caveat that it doesn't seem worth it?

Comment: Sure, that is the answer.

Comment: Can you just show how to deal with properties that are optional `number?` type so those result in `Type number | undefined is not assignable to number`, that's all ?

Comment: Um, I'm in the middle of writing the answer and I checked multiple times already if this worked for you.  I could try to look at this, but the reason I check in advance is so as not to waste time on something that doesn't actually meet the needs of the question.  Maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7G2PN) works but now I'm concerned that you'll find something else

Comment: Apologies for that, and no worries, even if I do find anything, I'll keep it to myself.

Comment: And, it's all good now!.

Comment: Heh it occurred to me while I was writing this that there *is* a way to view those two functions as doing "the same thing", but the generalization is kind of wacky.  I included it for completeness but I don't imagine it's worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually this is really two distinct functions:

```
function calculateObjSum<K extends PropertyKey>(
    arr: (Record<string, any> & Partial<Record<K, number>>)[],
    property: K
): number {
    const _arr: Partial<Record<K, number>>[] = arr;
    return _arr.reduce((a, v) => a + (v[property] ?? 0), 0)
}
const s1 = calculateObjSum([{ a: "abc", b: 123 }, { a: "def", b: 456 }], "b");
console.log(s1) // 579

function calculateNumSum(arr: number[]): number {
    return arr.reduce((a, v) => a + v, 0)
}
const s2 = calculateNumSum([789, 123, 456]);
console.log(s2) // 1368
```

The `calculateObjSum()` function is a somewhat more type-safe version of your example, since it will only allow inputs where `arr`'s elements have `number` properties at the `property` key.  And `calculateNumSum()` just adds up an array of numbers directly.

---

Now, if you really want to merge those into a single function, you will have to both set up something that looks like multiple call signatures (to make TypeScript happy) and multiple implementations (to make the function work at runtime).  For example, we can write the following [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) function:

```
// call signatures
function calculateSum<K extends PropertyKey>(
    arr: (Record<string, any> & Partial<Record<K, number>>)[],
    property: K
): number;
function calculateSum(arr: number[]): number;

// implementation
function calculateSum(arr: any[], property?: PropertyKey) {
    if (typeof property === "string") {
        return arr.reduce((a, v) => a + (v[property] ?? 0), 0);
    }
    return arr.reduce((a, v) => a + v, 0);
}

const s1 = calculateSum([{ a: "abc", b: 123 }, { a: "def", b: 456 }], "b");
console.log(s1) // 579

const s2 = calculateSum([789, 123, 456]);
console.log(s2) // 1368
```

That works as expected.  The implementation checks to see if `property` is a `string` as opposed to `undefined`, and delegates to the implementation of `calculateObjSum` or `calculateNumSum` depending on the result.

Note that it's somewhat less type safe than the two-function version, because TypeScript is unable to analyze that the implementation actually satisfies each call signature separately.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#13235](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13235) for more information.  That means you have to be careful not to mess up the implementation.

It is ultimately subjective whether or not a single `calculateSum` is better than a pair of `calculateObjSum` and `calculateNumSum` functions.  My opinion is that it is preferable to have two distinct functions that each have a clear single responsibility.  The single function version feels like two functions have been squashed into a single container.  This makes it harder for both the TypeScript compiler and the function implementer to reason about.  And I expect the same could be said for the caller.  But it's up to you.

---

Of course, one might decide to view both of these functions as specific instances of a more general function which takes a *variadic* number of property keys corresponding to a *path* into the array elements.  So `calculateSum(arr)` requires `arr`'s elements to be `number`, and `calculateSum(arr, "a")` requires the elements to be `{a?: number}`, and `calculateSum(arr, "a", "b", "c")` requires the elements to be `{a?: {b?: {c?: number}}}`.  If so, you could actually write that as a single function, possibly like this:

```
type DeepNumberDict<K extends PropertyKey[]> =
    K extends [infer K0 extends PropertyKey, ...infer KR extends PropertyKey[]] ?
    Record<string, any> & { [P in K0]?: DeepNumberDict<KR> } : number;

function calculateSum<K extends PropertyKey[]>(
    arr: DeepNumberDict<K>[], ...keys: K
): number {
    return arr.reduce((a, v) => a + ((keys.reduce((a, k) => (a ?? {})[k], v as any)) ?? 0), 0);
}
```

And you can see that it works:

```
const s1 = calculateSum([{ a: "abc", b: 123 }, { a: "def", b: 456 }], "b");
console.log(s1) // 579

const s2 = calculateSum([789, 123, 456]);
console.log(s2) // 1368

const s3 = calculateSum([{ a: { b: { c: 1 } } }, { a: { b: { c: 2 } } }], "a", "b", "c");
console.log(s3) // 3
```

Again, not sure it's worth it.  The function's behavior is too complicated for TypeScript to verify (so we need type assertions and/or `any`), and the `DeepNumberDict` utility type might be too impenetrable for the casual user.  Still, conceptually, at least, it's a single thing.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABASQCZTAGxQb2BWJQDMBXERAFwEsB7EFRXRcnMaqAeQCMArAMrkIAHgDSKKAA8uIDDBQAFAE704UFdQCe4qNoB8ACiIkzYFSoBcKIwCUoieioyiY1FbRABzADQowEEMUADJlCzpcUQcnFwl-EBFeTQMDAEoAbQBdX1MzYjg1DS1tG3E8lDSbRIhklQIKsycQdxQAfQtrcK1aKJjnV3EEpJSDbJQAXgDLAG5GkhUoanIVJg7LADpFjHJkIyMwfwA3NMmDAJQAalsjjML1TR0slAB+F5QABjT-L4qAXwqzVaMAAjJNmKx2JweAJhBAjBl8AEbAAiMC8RAo-y8GwggBMAGYUH9-EiwKisKQsSgcSgACwAVgAbMScigUbwUWk5k1GDB6DgoBscPRvEZQacAPSSlAMgDsAE5gBUKFQ6IwITg2BwuAA5ERwg6WaojFTZKooGp1Br5BZLFZMTpbKA7PYHY6nCbnMBXFBHH5pf6AvnUFAwPHglhaqF6g0iBFygAcCv8+IJ-kZTKy3ODLQFQpFYvDUplIIJTMTwABoEgsAQyBQAFlNN4XTaSKqaAwmFHtdC4RIpLIoPJFKoHiU9IYTLbiJ0bPZHAM3B4vH4AkFzmElBFejhoku4kNLabUpkcvMCkVHqUUOUzBarZoeR3KF2Nb2Y1BDfOT7VNOaJr-ioL7EJ26o9pCOrfvGv6BNo2T+PcxQ6C8Njjihuj6KchCzigtCkLYOgaPQhHITekwTFMKLuJ4Phcu2eHEIsyyrNMKjOq6UD7Icfqet6vpGLc5ElM8byfN8EmgfkAJ4SxDrsZxuzce6fFnBc1z+lJQa5sCYJTJ+0GGoiyLsuimLYrihLEqSpkopS1K0pmrL+ByXLSUC+bCqK4ogiWsqKsqvItKG4aRlB-bxhkSYpigaYZsy2YeXyXmFuKeL+WWFbKtW4DQPASCoI2YDaMkjEoMRqAACJQFAcD6sBVW0DQg4yHICjKNek76Nk5wTJed5Du1igZF4pCaHeHxDSOHUYTeU7+BsS1jRN4h2NNo6dROOhTtkYkDf0cS0Wu-jwVuBAoBkSj4Uw4gfFkaEoDVdUNXUTUtWt5x-CgQF1HMKpvhBmp9lwA6SG1M1jl1O09VkxgDb+z31aa73UBIYxsktGwANb6DAZQVI+prlWY8lsU62zKTxHrqT61z7Lj2gwEpbq8dj-G2D64n4H8mTY2yRwBIo8FpKc4lfAG0nVsFenhdGRlRWSqLmY5VlEiSF3kuyDmWfSzIueynI5jLqU+RKKDSgFSq6aFEYGRFoNRTFqaEglWbGyQnmCt5RYZRbpblpWNthkS9vy5F8ImVrSK0kiiC4sSica0rF2x8wNgRt9Wdsmi1Jua5mIe8QXsFmbBL+QSVZAA)

Comment: I see some merits in using the recursion type, for the reasons you mentioned and overload elimination so gonna use that. Thanks for including it.